# Why do I get ':' expected.ts(1005) as a Typescript error?

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, compiler-errors

Within the handleLogin function on my login page of my Next.js project I am getting this Typesricpt error: ':' expected.ts(1005)

Here is the function which is supposed to handle the login:

```
 const handleLogin = useCallback(async (credentials) => {

        if (!credentials.email) {
            return setError('email is missing')
        }
        if (!credentials.password) {
            return setError('password is missing')
        }
        try {
            setLoading(true)
            const response: SignInResponse | undefined = await signIn('credentials', { ...credentials, redirect: false })
            if (response?error && response.error === 'CredentialsSignin') {
                setError('email or password are wrong')
            } else {
                setError('')
                router.push('/')
            }
        } catch {
            setError('login failed')
        } finally {
            setLoading(false)
            console.log(error)
        }
    }, [router, error])
```

On this image you can see on which section of the code the error is showing up:
[image: errorLocation]

I have no clue which this error is showing up.

Comment: `response?error` if you want option chaining syntax is `response?.error`

Comment: This was closed for being "resolved in a way less likely to help future readers", but it helped me.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a typo.

The condition is looking like a ternary or conditional operator (`a ? b : c`) So the following line is expecting the colon:

`response?error && response.error === 'CredentialsSignin'`

However, that is not what you are intending. I think you have a typo and instead want optional chaining:

`response?.error && response.error === 'CredentialsSignin'`